# Cache-Control HTML Headers

Tags: html, caching, header, http-headers

In an effort to tell a browser's cache how to treat my site, I wanted to write some cache control rules in the header. There is a great resource [here](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), but I cant seem to find the correct cache control code for my situation.

Because my [website](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com) is static, I want the browser to always keep the data in its cache. BUT, the pages that do change (portfolio,blog) I want to be cached with an expiration of 3600 seconds.

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a hosting provider, I assume you can't control the actual HTTP headers? Instead, you can use [`<meta>` tags](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) to tell the browser what to do on a page-by-page basis.

As for headers, I'd rather just read straight from the horses mouth: see section 14.9 in [HTTP 1.1 Headers specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).